# How can i get text value from TextField while using a ViewModelProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form (a bunch of TextField widgets), i get the data from a REST API and load it to the view using a ViewModelProvider.
Now i want to press a button "Save", get the text value of the TextField widgets and pass the data to the REST API.

I searched for how to get the value of the TextField to use it elsewhere and all i found was similar to this :

```
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a TextEditingController as a variable
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: TextField(
          // Set the created TextEditingController as the controller of the Text Field
          controller: myController, 
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                // Use the text attribute of the TextEditingController variable
                content: Text(myController.text),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Show me the value!',
        child: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(This code snippet was taken from the [Flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input))

My problem is that i use a ViewModelProvider and i need to create the TextEditingController inside the 
builder attribute of the ViewModelProvider to set the text that was retreived from the HTTP call.

Here is my current code, i left only one TextField because they are practically the same.

```
class SettingsView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<SettingsViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: SettingsViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) => model.getSettings(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Host',
                ),
                controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  TextEditingValue(
                    text: model.settings == null? '' :model.settings.host,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: CallToAction("Save"),
                onTap: saveData,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveData() {
  }
}
```

So the question is, how to pass the text value of the TextField to the saveData method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thiago Dong Chen i managed to find the solution to my problem.

Thiago suggested that i create a `TextEditingController` variable and set its text value in `onModelReady` as follows

```
onModelReady: (model) {
  myController.text = model.settings == null ? '' : model.settings.host;
  model.getSettings();
},
```

The problem is even in `onModelReady` the `model.settings` is still `null`. But his solution put me in the right path. I'm new to Flutter, Dart and the anonymous functions. Seeing that i can change the `=>` to a more classic `{}` made me realize that i can do the same in `builder` and do more that just setting the widget tree.

Here is the full code :

```
class SettingsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SettingsViewState createState() => _SettingsViewState();
}

class _SettingsViewState extends State<SettingsView> {
  TextEditingController _hostController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<SettingsViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: SettingsViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) => model.getSettings(),
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        _hostController.text = model.settings == null ? null : model.settings.host;
        return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Host",
                ),
                controller: _hostController,
                inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: CallToAction("Save"),
                onTap: saveData,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
        }
    );
  }

  void saveData() async{
    var _api = locator<Api>();
    bool b = await _api.setSettings(SettingItemModel(
        host: _hostController.text));
    String message = '';
    if (b) {
      message = 'Data saved to the database!';
    } else {
      message = 'Couldn\'t save the data';
    }
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to init the TextEditingController?

If so, you can initialize the text of the controler on onModelReady, and declare the controler outside of build.

```
class _SettingsViewState extends State<SettingsView> {
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<SettingsViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: SettingsViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) {
        myController.text =
            model.settings == null ? '' : model.settings.host;
        model.getSettings();
      },
      builder: (context, model, child) => Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Host'),
                controller: myController,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: CallToAction("Save"),
                onTap: saveData,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveData() {
    print('save data ${myController.text}');
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I even changed the code to this

onModelReady: (model) {
        model.getSettings();
        myController.text = model.settings == null
            ? null
            : model.settings.host;
      },

but the model.settings is still null